# IBM MQ - test headers are correctly set. getStringProperty() throws Exception

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I want to test that my code sets headers correctly before the message is being set.
I'm unable to get properties I set in code - I'm getting following stacktrace:

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2471'.
at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.getProperty(MQMessage.java:5697)
at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.getStringProperty(MQMessage.java:6952)
at com.ibm.mq.MQMessage.getStringProperty(MQMessage.java:6928)
........
```

Here's the *simplified* test code:

```
@Autowired
MessageSender messageSender;

@Mock
MQAccessor mqAccessor;

@Test
public void headersCorrectlySet() throws MQException {

    MQTopic topic = mock(MQTopic.class);
    when(mqAccessor.getTopic(anyString())).thenReturn(topic);

    messageSender.setHeadersAndSentMessage(new MyObject(...));

    verify(topic).put(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<MQMessage>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object o) {
            MQMessage msg = (MQMessage)o;
            return msg.getStringProperty("myProperty").equals("myValue"); // <-- error
        }
    }));
}
```

This is how I set header in MessageSender:

```
msg.setStringProperty("myProperty", "myValue");
```

I would like to note, that in reality no message is being sent to the MQ, I'm mocking out that part.
It's weird that`setStringProperty(...)` works, but corresponding `getStringProperty(...)` throws an Exception.
How should the code be tested in this situation?

Comment: A lot more verbose, but I prefer adding null checks to everything before I get a NullpointerException.

Comment: Yes, the code is simplified for clarity.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q044820_.htm says the property is not available. Are you sure you are putting the right property in. Also are you sure you are not reading some other message ?

Comment: Thanks @RomainHippeau, your comment helped me. 2471 is indeed property unavailable. I mocked my code setting the property by accident.